# System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class

Tags: c#

**ExtendedCommandManager.cs**

```
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
var types = assembly.SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes()).Where(p => typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(p));
foreach (var type in types)
{
   source.Commands.Add((ICommand) Activator.CreateInstance(type)); 
}

return source;
```

type inherited ICcommand But why is there an error?

**Error**

```
Unhandled exception. System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& hasNoDefaultCtor)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtorSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at BASE.CommandControllers.ExtendedCommandManager.Load[T](T source) in D:\CLang\DicordProject\Discord\BASE\CommandControllers\ExtendedCommandManager.cs:line 16
```

Comment: Have you read the error? It's giving you a pretty major hint! It looks like you have a class that inherits from `ICommand` that is an abstract class which can not be created. You probably just need to test whether the class you are attempting to create is abstract or not `type.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract;`

Comment: At least one of the types you are trying to create an instance of is abstract. Abstract types can only be inherited from, they can not be instantiated.
You could try printing each type you're trying to instantiate and see which one's causing the exception

Comment: nobody ever reads exception messages :( _"Cannot create an abstract class"_ means that you can't create an instance of **abstract** class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But why is there an error?

Because you're trying to create an instance of an abstract class (rather than a concrete class derived from that abstract class). You can't do that with reflection, just like you can't do it with regular code. If you were to try writing code of `var command = new FooCommand();` (where `FooComand` is the type that it's failing on) that code would fail to compile.

Your code for checking which types to instantiate should include `!p.IsAbstract` to filter out abstract classes that implement `ICommand`.

Comment: `just like you can't do it with regular code`  I think you mean directly.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5602284/1985541

Comment: @Zuzlx: Well, I mean "of precisely that type rather than a derived type".

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong. You can't create an instance of an abstract class.

You need to filter your types so that they don't include abstract types. like this:

```
var types = assembly.SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes()).Where(p => !p.IsAbstract && typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a instance of both abstract class and interface. Because it does not contain complete implementation. 
So, first implement it.

Comment: It's not necessarily because it does not contain complete implementation. Abstract classes may be completely implemented (unlike interfaces)

Comment: yes it may have, and this has been discussed before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670991/can-we-instantiate-an-abstract-class

Answer (score 0):

See this [Microsoft Doc For Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)

Like most abstract class implementation in most languages, you can't create an object of that specifically. It's used as a building block, typically for common code shared amongst other classes.

The Execption is correct. When you loaded your classes / objects by reflection using the interface as it's identifier, one of the classes that implemented that interface is abstract and can't be instanciated with `Activator.CreateInstance`, but your code doesn't know that until runtime as it can do type checking on stuff created dynamically at runtime.