# Call Constructor from abstract class with readonly values

Tags: c#, constructor, abstract-class, readonly

Im trying to call this constructor from Student into the collegestudent.

Here is the constructor:

```
abstract class Student
{
    public readonly string FirstName;
    public readonly string LastName;
    public readonly string StudentID;

    public Student(string Value)
    {
        FirstName = Value;
        LastName = Value;
        StudentID = Value;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return FirstName + LastName + StudentID; }
    }
}
```

Here is CollegeStudent:

```
class CollegeStudent : Student, IMathClass
{
    public Student(string Tim, string russell, string studentid)
    {
        FirstName = Tim;
        LastName = russell;
        studentID = studentid;
    }
}
```

Im getting following errors

- "Method must have a return type"
- "A readonly field cannot be assigned to"

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601777/constructor-of-an-abstract-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why just don't call `base` constructor? Btw, `CollegeStudent` declaration is invalid, constructor can't be named as `Student`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be the initialization order. A `readonly` variable can only be assigned once (within the constructor when it's a class variable). When you create the object, the variable will already be initialized by the `Student` constructor because this will be called first (before the constructor of `CollegeStudent`). When you try to initialize it (again) in the `CollegeStudent` constructor, it's already initialized and therefore an error raise.

Furthermore, I'd suggest some changes:

**First:** Make the properties not `readonly` but define only a public getter and private/protected setter. This might already solve your problem.

```
public string Firstname {get; protected set;}
```

**Second:** The next thing is the constructor and the parameter names of your `CollegeStundet`. As these are parameters (variables containing information) they look really strange. Better would be:

```
public CollegeStudent(string firstName, string lastName, string studentId)
```

You will use it like this to create a new `CollegeStudent` object:

```
// this uses polymorphism as all CollegeStudnet are Student
Student studentX = new CollegeStundet("Tim", "Russel", "123AAA");
```

**Third:** Setting all the properties to the same value in the default constructor is really odd. In general, this will never be a good idea. Provide at least on general constructor to initialize all three to different values. You can still let them be "empty" (null - when using a default constructor) when you already followed my **first** suggestion.

```
 Student(string firstName, string lastName, string studentId);

 // the base keyword will pass the values to the constructor of Student
 CollegeStudent(string firstName, string lastName, string studentId) : base(firstName, lastName, studentId)
```

But in general, I'd suggest to initialize them in the class where they are defined (`Student` constructor in this case). When you need to change the values from outside `Student` and you really want the values to be not writeable, there went something wrong with your concept.

Comment: I see what you are saying and this helped out alot, Im just getting into c# so knowing this stuff really helped out, thanks Alex!